# Print particular property in JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

When I print the variable it prints below array, Is there a way to print OwnerId from the below array, please.

```
Array [
  Place {
    "lng": -0.0109167,
    "ownerId": test,
    "title": "Test",
  },
  Place {
    "lng": -0.0108539,
    "ownerId": 234,
    "title": "Server test",
  },
  Place {
    "lng": -0.0108778,
    "ownerId": 234,
    "title": "Tile",
  },]
```

Comment: What is `Place`? Is that the output of `variable.toString()`?

Comment: Place is a class name: class Place {
  constructor(lng, ownerId, title) {
    this.lng = lng;
    this.ownerId = ownerId;
    this.title = title;
      }
}

Comment: it sounds like you want to do something in one line like https://jmespath.org/ is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```js
const a = [{
    "lng": -0.0109167,
    "ownerId": 435,
    "title": "Test",
}, {
    "lng": -0.0108539,
    "ownerId": 234,
    "title": "Server test",
}, {
    "lng": -0.0108778,
    "ownerId": 234,
    "title": "Tile",
}];

console.log(a.map(x=>x.ownerId))
```